# Derived class template doesn't see the base class's member

Tags: c++

iam developing a class that derives from another , but i am getting stuck , with this code:

```
template <class A, class B, class C>
class BaseClass
{
public:
    BaseClass(){}
    virtual void amethod( A* aPtr=0)
    {
        mAPtr=aPtr;
    }
    virtual void init()=0;
protected:
    A * mAPtr;
    B* mBPtr;
    C * mCPtr;
};
template <class A,class B,class C>
class ChildClass: public BaseClass<A,B,C>
{
public:
    ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0):mAPtr(aAptr)
      ,mBPtr(aBPtr)
      ,mCPtr(aCPtr)
    {}

};
int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler out says that the child class doesnt have any of the parent field.

Compiler out:

```
 In constructor 'ChildClass<A, B, C>::ChildClass(A*, B*, C*)'
 In constructor 'ChildClass<A, B, C>::ChildClass(A*, B*, C*)'
error: class 'ChildClass<A, B, C>' does not have any field named 'mAPtr'
error: class 'ChildClass<A, B, C>' does not have any field named 'mBPtr'
error: class 'ChildClass<A, B, C>' does not have any field named 'mCPtr'
```

i have searching in google but i cannot find an answer:
Thx in advance

Comment: I'm unsure, but maybe you can't initialize inherited fields with constructor initializers. Try initializing them inside the constructor's body.

Comment: (incidentally, what has STL to do with this question?)

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 compiles this code perfectly.

Comment: Like @MatteoItalia, I wonder what the STL has to do with this. I edited the question to reflect what's in the body of the question. Please add details about how this touches on STL if it really does :)

Comment: @Helix, that's a bug in VS2012 then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Juan, this code:

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
{
    mAPtr = aAptr;  // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
    mBPtr = aBPtr; // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
    mCPtr = aCPtr; // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
}
```

will give to you the same compiler error, you need to explicitly write the base class, in the following way:

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
{
    BaseClass<A,B,C>::mAPtr = aAptr;
    BaseClass<A,B,C>::mBPtr = aBPtr;
    BaseClass<A,B,C>::mCPtr = aCPtr;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot constructor-initialize the base member variables directly in the derived class constructor.

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
    : mAPtr(aAptr)  // <-- Member belongs to parent
    , mBPtr(aBPtr) // <-- Member belongs to parent
    , mCPtr(aCPtr) // <-- Member belongs to parent
{
}
```

You can either default construct them in the base constructor and them assign them (since they are protected)

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
{
    mAPtr = aAptr;  // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
    mBPtr = aBPtr; // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
    mCPtr = aCPtr; // <-- Member belongs to parent but you can access it
}
```

Or you can modify the parent class constructor

```
BaseClass( A* aAptr, B * aBPtr0, C* aCPtr)
    : mAPtr(aAptr)
    , mBPtr(aBPtr)
    , mCPtr(aCPtr)
{
}
```

and

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
  : BaseClass(aAptr, aBPtr, aCPtr)
{
}
```

Also, remember that you need to define a void init() method in your derived class

Answer (score 5):

You cannot initialize base class' data members in a derived class' constructor's initializer list. You could assign them in the body of the constructor:

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0) {
  mAPtr = aAptr;
  mBPtr = aBPtr;
  mCPtr = aCPtr;
}
```

However, the base class looks badly designed: its only constructor doesn't initialize the three data members at all (not even to `NULL`), so they end up containing random garbage. It would probably make sense to have a three-parameter constructor in `BaseClass` that would initialize the data members; the constructor of `ChildClass` would simply forward to that, via its initialzier list.

Answer (score 2):

using the anwser from above , i have changed a little bit :

```
ChildClass( A* aAptr =0, B * aBPtr= 0, C* aCPtr= 0)
    {
        this->mAPtr=aAptr;
        this->mBPtr=aBPtr;
        this->mCPtr=aCPtr;
    }
```

without the this pointer the compiler doesnt see the variable from parent.
Thx!, by the way the compilation was for Linux usign Gcc compiler gcc version 4.7.3.